# Chrome - Border radius does not work when background:none

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have the following css styles for an input tag...

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="search" class="border" />
</div>

.container{
  background: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.border{
  background:none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

When i set background: none, the border-radius did not work in chrome but works well in all other browsers including ie9. So why in chrome, **border radius doesn't work when background:none** ?

**Example :**
http://jsfiddle.net/TSKpN/5/

Comment: Well, does it have a border at all?

Comment: Yes it has... I forgot to put in the code... Sorry...

Comment: seems to be working for me...
http://jsfiddle.net/8NKEv/
what version of chrome?

Comment: It doesn't work on input tags only... Works fine on div's...

Comment: still working fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/8NKEv/1/

Comment: I don't know. It works fine on jsfiddle and on all other browser except chrome. I couldn't post sample images since I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it. Does this fiddle work in chrome?

Comment: Check this out in chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/TSKpN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
<style>
#some-id{  
    background:none; 
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="some-id">
</body>
```